# Are there any GUIs for or with FFmpeg where I can select / clip exact frame timestamps, and copy both of them simulatenously or as a command?

Tags: video, gui, video-editing, macos

I make lots of clips with ffmpeg where I clip videos using the `-ss` and `-to` arguments. What I want is a GUI to see the video, seek exact times, and get exact timestamps of where I want to clip, so I could clip to exact frames. After I select the start and end timestamps, I want to see either both timestamps, or a command like `ffmpeg -ss -to -i ...`, and either in a text box I can copy, or button / a way to copy it to my clipboard.

I haven't looked too much into it but I looked at losslesscut and avidemux, but it doesn't seem like they do, unless I'm wrong. I use a Mac btw.